# Select count of rows with group by multiple columns with minimum of 1 of the columns

Tags: oracle, group-by, min

```
Table Structure:
CASENUM NUMBER(15,0)    No
DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(150 BYTE)  Yes
COMPLETED   VARCHAR2(5 BYTE)    Yes
USERID  VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)   Yes
TRIGGERDATE DATE    Yes
DOCUMENTID  VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)   Yes
ROWSEQ  NUMBER  Yes
UPDATEDON   DATE    Yes
TRIGTYPE    VARCHAR2(5 BYTE)    Yes
```

I need to select count of cases per trigger type, per date 
if there are two similar triggers for a same case then it should only be counted once and should be counted in the oldest date.

```
 SELECT 
  TRIGTYPE                          ,
  COUNT(TRIGTYPE) AS PENDINGTRIGGERS,
  TRUNC(TRIGGERDATE)
   FROM TBLNABTRIGGERDETAILS 
   WHERE
 COMPLETED     ='false'
AND TRIGTYPE     IS NOT NULL
and TRIGGERDATE > '17-JAN-2015'
GROUP BY TRUNC(TRIGGERDATE), TRIGTYPE
ORDER BY TRUNC(TRIGGERDATE), TRIGTYPE;
```

output

```
TRIGTYPE PENDINGTRIGGERS        TRUNC(TRIGGERDATE)        
-------- ---------------------- ------------------------- 
DOC      1                      17-01-15                  
NEW      3                      17-01-15                  
DOC      2                      18-01-15                  
FUP      1                      18-01-15                  
REJ      1                      18-01-15
```

5 rows selected

data in the table

```
CASENUM COMPLETED   TRIGGERDATE TRIGTYPE
111953805   false   18-01-15    REJ
111953805   false   18-01-15    FUP
111953805   false   18-01-15    DOC
111953805   false   18-01-15    DOC
111953805   false   17-01-15    DOC
111953746   false   17-01-15    NEW
111953805   false   17-01-15    NEW
111953804   false   17-01-15    NEW
```

I want to count DOC only once and it should be under 17th Jan.
Is this possible using single query?

Expected Output:

```
TRIGTYPE PENDINGTRIGGERS        TRUNC(TRIGGERDATE)        
-------- ---------------------- ------------------------- 
DOC      1                      17-01-15                  
NEW      3                      17-01-15                          
FUP      1                      18-01-15                  
REJ      1                      18-01-15
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you could use DISTINCT... So replace `from tblna` with `from (select DISTINCT casenum,triggerdate, tigtype from tblna)`

Comment: good question, with all the detail we need **except** expected output! Please add this to your question. Notice how at least 2 people have said "If I understand you correctly"? Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood right, you wish just not to consider rows if it's CASENUM+TRIGTYPE is equals of some older record's CASENUM+TRIGTYPE. So you should use MINUS or anti-join to filter these records. For example:

```
SELECT 
  TRIGTYPE                          ,
  COUNT(TRIGTYPE) AS PENDINGTRIGGERS,
  TRUNC(TRIGGERDATE)
FROM (
  select t1.* 
  from TBLNABTRIGGERDETAILS t1
  left outer join TBLNABTRIGGERDETAILS t2
    on (t1.casenum = t2.casenum and
        t1.trigtype = t2.trigtype and
        t1.triggerdate > t2.triggerdate)
  where t2.triggerdate is null)
WHERE
 COMPLETED = 'false'
 AND TRIGTYPE IS NOT NULL
 and TRIGGERDATE > '17-JAN-2015'
GROUP BY TRUNC(TRIGGERDATE), TRIGTYPE
ORDER BY TRUNC(TRIGGERDATE), TRIGTYPE;
```

P.S. It assumes that there is no two same events with equal dates. It it's wrong you should tune join condition.

Comment: Thanks Sander,It works fine with no duplicate rows for same date and same trigger type. But Desnt work when there are multiple rows for same date for same trigger type and the date is oldest.

Comment: Did you read P.S. section? :) You should tune join condition. For example, use something like (t1.triggerdate > t2.triggerdate or t1.triggerdate = t2.triggerdate and t1.rowid > t2.rowid)

Comment: Hi Sander,I wrote different query which works with duplicate as well.


SELECT TRIGTYPE ,
  COUNT(TRIGTYPE) AS PENDINGTRIGGERS,
  TRUNC(TRIGGERDATE)
FROM
  (SELECT I.TRIGTYPE,
    I.CASENUM,
    MIN (I.TRIGGERDATE) TRIGGERDATE
  FROM TBLNABTRIGGERDETAILS I
  WHERE TRIGGERDATE > '16-JAN-2015'
  GROUP BY I.TRIGTYPE,
    I.CASENUM
  )
GROUP BY TRUNC(TRIGGERDATE),
  TRIGTYPE
ORDER BY TRUNC(TRIGGERDATE),
  TRIGTYPE;